# Dismiss UITableView Cell upon selection in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autocomplete, viewcontroller

I have a UITableView Cell in a View Controller serving as a display for autocompletion for a text field. However, selecting one of the autocomplete suggestions does not dismiss the table view cell. I have tried "self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(True, completion: nil)" inside my didSelectRowAtIndexPath function for UITableView. Any thoughts?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var RecName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Body: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var RecEmail: UITextField!

var emailArray = ""
var emailNSArray = [""]
var autocomplete = [String]()
var tycard2 = ""
var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef?
@IBOutlet var autocompleteTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //email
    RecEmail.delegate = self
    //autocomplete
    autocompleteTableView!.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView!.dataSource = self
    autocompleteTableView!.scrollEnabled = true
    autocompleteTableView!.hidden = true
    println(tycard2)
}

func createAddressBook(){
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error).takeRetainedValue()
}


func textToImage(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint:CGPoint)->UIImage{

    // Setup the font specific variables
    var textColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 20)!

    //Setup the image context using the passed image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)

    //Setups up the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
    ]

    //Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
    inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

    // Creating a point within the space that is as bit as the image.
    var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

    //Now Draw the text into an image.
    drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    // Create a new image out of the images we have created
    var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context now that we have the image we need
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //And pass it back up to the caller.
    return newImage

}


func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    autocompleteTableView!.hidden = false
    var substring = (self.RecEmail.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    return true
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
    autocomplete.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let emailArray = delegate.emailArray
    var emailNSArray = emailArray.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

    for curString in emailNSArray
    {
        println(curString)
        var myString: NSString! = curString as NSString
        var substringRange: NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring)
        if (substringRange.location == 0)
        {
            autocomplete.append(curString)
        }
    }

    autocompleteTableView!.reloadData()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return autocomplete.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let autoCompleteRowIdentifier = "AutoCompleteRowIdentifier"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(autoCompleteRowIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if let tempo1 = cell
    {
        let index = indexPath.row as Int
        cell!.textLabel!.text = autocomplete[index]
    } else
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: autoCompleteRowIdentifier)
    }
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("dismiss")
    RecEmail.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: For that, you can again hide `autocompleteTableView` after cell selection.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to dismiss a `ViewController` not a table view cell. If you want to remove a cell, just delete current row index in your data source (here to be your [String] array `autocomplete`), and do reload data.